# How to open kotlin repl using kotlin-native-linux?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I just downloaded kotlin compiler `kotlin-native-linux-1.3.61.tar.gz`
from here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.61

But when I try to open the repl, as proposed in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#running-the-repl), running:

```
/opt/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.61/bin/kotlinc
```

I get:

```
error: you have not specified any compilation arguments. No output has been produced.
```

The documentation says: "We can run the compiler without parameters to have an interactive shell"

How can I open the kotlin repl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repl` is available in `kotlin-compiler-1.3.61.zip`.

`kotlin-native` is for compiling Kotlin code to native binaries, which can run without a virtual machine.

Probably there is no reason to add `repl` and `-script` support on `kotlinc` of `kotlin-native` package.